# How to prove that $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \sum_{r=1}^n \dfrac 1 {\sqrt{n^2 + r}} \right) = 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

We have to show that 
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \dfrac 1 {\sqrt{n^2 +1}} +\dfrac 1 {\sqrt{n^2 +2}} + \dfrac 1 {\sqrt{n^2 +3}} + \ldots + \dfrac 1 {\sqrt{n^2 +n}} \right) = 1$$

Now, I thought of doing it as a definite integral, however the terms don't translate into a function of $\left(\dfrac r n\right)$. I tried searching wolfram-alpha, but it used Hurwitz-zeta function, of which I have no clue. (This is an assignment problem)

Comment: Use squeeze theorem.

Comment: **Hint:** $0<1,2,\ldots,n<n^2$

Comment: Use squeeze theorem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\left({1\over \sqrt{n^2+1}}+{1\over \sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+{1\over \sqrt{n^2+n}}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124342/find-lim-limitsn-to-infty-left1-over-sqrtn211-over-sqrtn22)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** For all $n\in \mathbb N$ it holds that

$$ \dfrac n {\sqrt{n^2 +n}} \leq \dfrac 1 {\sqrt{n^2 +1}} +\dfrac 1 {\sqrt{n^2 +2}} + \dfrac 1 {\sqrt{n^2 +3}} + \ldots + \dfrac 1 {\sqrt{n^2 +n}}\leq \dfrac n {\sqrt{n^2 +1}}.$$