# Monotony problem with sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

Let us consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ such that 
$$a_n=\frac {1}{\sqrt {n^2+1}}+ \frac {1}{\sqrt {n^2+2}} + \dots +\frac {1}{\sqrt {n^2+n}}.$$ Show that the sequence is not monotone.

I found the problem, but the solution is wrong.

Comment: This sequence is an increasing one. It converges to $1$.

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948049/how-to-prove-that-lim-n-to-infty-left-sum-r-1n-dfrac-1-sqrtn2-r.